# I'm getting ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED from my website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have a domain that I got from NameCheap: [www.app.flerr.io](http://www.app.flerr.io).

I configured the domain in AWS with Route53, CloudFront and S3.

I uploaded the static website to the relevant S3 bucket.

When I try to reach my website, I get the following error: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED.

[image]

Although, when I reach the website through S3 static website hosting it's working:

[image]

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Route53:

I have one `A` record that traffics to `<id>.cloudfront.net`:

[image]

I have one `NS` record that traffics to 4 NS URLs.

I have one `SOA` record.

I have one `CNAME` record.

Answer (score 0):

ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED usually refers to a DNS problem.

You already verified that S3 URL is working correctly.
Now, verify that Cloudfront is working correctly by pasting the Cloudfront URL in your browser (`<id>.cloudfront.com` or something similar).

If both of them are working, means that your problem is indeed DNS (and therefore Route53) related.

Use any DNS Lookup page to see if your domain (flerr.io) is correctly set up.
https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=a%3awww.app.flerr.io&run=toolpage

---

With the information given that's the best we can do, if you share your Route53 Hosted Zones we could see if anything is wrong

Comment: So yes, when I use the CloudFront URL I can reach my website, so there is a problem with the DNS itself. I have edited my post with the relevant Route53 information.

Comment: how does your `A record that traffics to <id>.cloudfront.net` looks like ? Can wee see it ?

Comment: I have added it to the post. The record name is ```app.flerr.io```.

Answer (score 0):

If you bought `flerr.io.` - you dont need to create a new zone for `app.flerr.io.` (you can, but its not required - this is called DNS delegation). You just need to create a record named `www.app` inside `flerr.io.` as an A or CNAME to your destination.

When i use [dig](https://www.digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=www.app.flerr.io%0D%0Aapp.flerr.io%0D%0Aflerr.io&type=ANY&ns=resolver&useresolver=8.8.4.4&nameservers=) to test the DNS i get the following results:

- `dig flerr.io.` shows A records
- `dig app.flerr.io.` shows A records - and appears to be its own DNS delegation zone (was that deliberate)?
- `dig www.app.flerr.io.` does not return any records - this is why you cant resolve your site.

I think the solution for you is to create the `www.app` records in the `flerr.io.` zone and ignore the `app.flerr.io.` zone you created. If your trying to use the zone `app.flerr.io.` (and its been setup properly in `flerr.io.`) you would just create the `www` record.

Comment: Thank you for the informative answer! So I need to create new ```A``` record in ```flerr.io``` zone with record name ```www.app``` and traffic it to which url?

Comment: For CloudFront I would suggest `www.app` is a CNAME with Alias turned on pointing to `<id>.cloudfront.com`

Comment: Ok, now it partially works. I can access to ```https://app.flerr.io``` but not to ```app.flerr.io``` or ```www.app.flerr.io```.